# How to resolve syntax error with dynamic PostgreSQL statement

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, syntax

Suppose I have a table called my_table that has 3 columns

```
id   | name |  state
-----+------+--------
1020 | 'A ' | 'VA'   
-----+------+--------
1021 | 'B'  | 'VA'
-----+------+--------
1022 | 'C'  | 'NC'
```

I am having an issue with a simple dynamic statement I am trying to run. I don't see anything wrong with this, do you?

```
 EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table WHERE id = '|| 1021;
```

I am just running this standalone. It should execute. Instead, I get a `ERROR: syntax error at or near "'SELECT....`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the complete code of your function (or procedure)

Comment: I just want to run this standalone to test. I added the table with simple data.

Comment: You can't use procedural code (PL/pgSQL) inside SQL. But your example does not need any dynamic SQL at all, so what's wrong with simply running `SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table WHERE id = 1021;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html) in plain SQL is used to run prepared statements.
Straight quote from the docs:

> EXECUTE is used to execute a previously prepared statement. Since prepared statements only exist for the duration of a session, the prepared statement must have been created by a PREPARE statement executed earlier in the current session.

You're probably mixing it up with pl/pgsql [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), which is totally different.

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely trying to use the pl/pgsql version. SO why won'yt it work. What do I have to add here?

Comment: @gwydion93 you can only use PL/pgSQL inside a stored procedure/function or a [DO block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). You can't mix procedural code and "plain SQL"